# Should new Access Token be generated with page reload and should Refresh Tokens be invalidated

Tags: javascript, authentication, security, oauth-2.0, authorization

The following AuthFlow is present in the project I'm working on:

1. When the user logs in he gets `access-token` which is stored in memory in Javascript and which is then appended as a header to each API request.
2. When `access-token` expires, the `/refresh-token` route is called with the `refresh-token` (httpOnly cookie)

When the user closes and refreshes the browser card, a call is made to `refresh-token` for a new `access-token`.
I suspect there is no way to use the earlier (still working) `access-token` by having the user close the browser tab.
What about an unused but still working `access-token`? Shouldn't we invalidate it somehow? Or is that why we use `access-tokens` - so that we can generate many of them (e.g. with each refresh page) and not worry about the fact that there are many of them, because they have a short duration?

I also read about `refresh-token` rotation (invalidation after use). Is it strongly recommended and should we store user `refresh-tokens` in the database so that they are invalidated with each request for a new `access-token`? If so - does it consist in storing only one - current refresh token and then invalidating it (how is it done), or should the entire "list" be kept?

Answer (score 1):

**SHORT ANSWER**

If using access tokens in JavaScript, keep them in memory and refresh them on every page reload. Keep them short lived. They will be discarded when the page is unloaded. Also use the strongest setting for refresh tokens, to rotate them. Since you are storing refresh tokens in HTTP only cookies, any cookie rewrites on token refresh will come into immediate effect across all browser tabs.

**LONGER ANSWER**

Once you take the step of storing refresh tokens in HTTP only cookies, you may as well also store access tokens in the same way. Keeping tokens out of the browser is likely to be seen as more secure, with better understood threats. The [OAuth for Browser Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#section-6.2) doc has further information.